# Imported SVG shows circles instead of squares

Tags: import, svg

---

I have some wierd issue with a .svg Import, here's the vectorized image on Illustrator:

[image]

But when i import it on Blender, it looks like this:

[image]

It transforms squares into circles. And i have no clue why it does that.

I have the same issue with multiple image.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: maybe try to scale it up and save in illustrator, and import again

Comment: Tried, still do the same thing :(

Comment: could you please share your svg? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ho. I was about to send it and i just see that the problem is the svg. The export on Illustrator have made thoses circle... I look on the web why he does that...

Comment: Ok so if you solved your problem, answer to yourself so that we know how you did it  ;)

Comment: Have you tried importing this in Inkscape and then from there exporting to svg? Blender seems to have fewer problems with Inkscape, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was in Illustrator. The Image trace tool considered some rectangle as Circle. I had to convert all part how gave me Circle.

Full answered here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118502/131137

Thanks to him (And you too !) !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Illustrator trace settings. I tried to trace it in Inkscape, and succeed. There are no circles, just few objects in blender - one for each color.

[image: Inkscape export]

Comment: Problem was in Illustrator yhea.
Gonna try with Inkscape next time maybe.